# Showing complex continuity by using the definiton.

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I want to show continuity of the following function by using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition:
\begin{align}
f:\mathbb{C} \ &\times \ \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \\
(z,w) &\rightarrow z + w
\end{align}
We use the Euclidean norm as the measure for distance in the domain.
The real problem comes down to that I can't seem to find an inequality that can help us. Since we use the Euclidean Norm, I thought we could perhaps use the following inequality: $|(z,w)| \leq \sqrt{\text{Re}(z)^2 + \text{Im}(z)^2 + \text{Re}(w)^2 + \text{Im}(w)^2}$.

We choose $(x,y) \in \mathbb{C} \ \times \ \mathbb{C}$ randomly. Also we choose $\epsilon > 0 $ randomly. We also choose $(c,d) \in \mathbb{C} \ \times \ \mathbb{C}$ randomly. Then, we need to show that there is a $\delta$ such that if $|(x,y) - (c,d)| \leq \delta$ then $|x + y - c - d| \leq \epsilon$.

If we then start with $|x+y-c-d| \leq |x-c| + |y-d|$.
I feel as if we can use this to find the delta that we need, but I don't know how to exactly.

I'd appreciate a hint to try and show this continuity by using the definition.

Thanks for your time,

K. Kamal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $|(x,y)-(c,d)|^2 \leq \delta^2$.

Let's expand what we have on the left side of the inequality: $|(x,y)-(c,d)|=|(x-c,y-d)| = \sqrt{(|x-c|^2 + |y-d|^2}$, just like $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So, taking squares at both sides, you get that $|(x,y)-(c,d)|^2 = |x-c|^2 + |y-d|^2$, so:

$|x-c|^2 + |y-d|^2 \leq \delta^2$

You want to relate that with $|x-c| + |y-d|$.

First prove that $|x-c|^2 \leq \delta^2$. Then you have that $|x-c| \leq \delta$.

Do something similar for $|y-d|$. Which $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon)$ can you pick now to get the desired result?

Comment: Since the absolute values of $|y - d|^2$ is surely greater than or equal to 0, the equality $|x-c|^2 \leq \delta^2$ holds. Therefore we have $|x-c| \leq \delta$. In the same way we can find $|y-d| \leq \delta$. Therefore, if we choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ we would find what we are looking for.

However, I don't exactly how from your first inequality the second inequality follows, i.e. $|(x,y) -(c,d)|^2 \leq \delta^2 \rightarrow |x-c|^2+|y-d|^2 \leq \delta^2$.

Comment: I'll edit it. A comment: the usual notation for "implies" it \Rightarrow ($\Rightarrow$), not \rightarrow ($\rightarrow$)

Comment: There, I edited my answer!